# Windows 8.1 dropped Camera App from filepicker

Tags: camera, photo, windows-8.1, filepicker

I am developing a LOB web app using jquery mobile for Windows tablets. I was going to use the feature that was available on Windows 8 which is to take a picture on the file picker. and send the image in a form. However, since I updated yesterday my computer to win 8.1 there is no Camera App in the file picker anymore. I don't know if there is a way to have it back there. Or if there is another photo app that implements the filepicker contract.

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem as I have a few apps that rely heavily on this. I've ran through the MSDN library and couldn't find anything useful. Do update me if you have any findings, thanks!